# Geolocation on-demand via text messaging. Is it possible?

Tags: android, geolocation, sms, messaging

I know this might sound crazy, but my nana somehow gets extremely worried about me and where I am. So I don't want to use apps like life360. Is there any way to have a setup to whenever she texts me with something like "where are you?" She'll be sent a set of coordinates or something that could geolocate my phone without having to constantly drain my battery?

Comment: I don't *think* this is possible in newer versions of Android (it used to be).  I don't think you can read SMS without being the default SMS app.  It's possible you could do something clever with reading your SMS app's notifications via a notification listener.

Comment: Note that "how to code that entire app" is somewhat too broad for a Stack Overflow question, if that's what you're asking (rather than for an app recommendation).